# Python WSGI handler directly in Apache .htaccess, not in VirtualHost

Tags: python, .htaccess, mod-wsgi, wsgi, bottle

I know how to have a Python Bottle server:

```
import os
from bottle import route, template, default_app
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return template('Hello world')

application = default_app()
```

run with WSGI, configured like this with Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/wsgi_test/app.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

**Is it possible to do the WSGI configuration directly in the `.htaccess`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the [doc](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html#mounting-the-wsgi-application), and it seems that the answer is no, sadly:

> When using mod_cgi to host CGI applications, this would be done using the ScriptAlias directive. For mod_wsgi, the directive is instead called WSGIScriptAlias:
>
> ```
> WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi
> ```
>
> This directive can only appear in the main Apache configuration files. The directive can be used at server scope but would normally be placed within the VirtualHost container for a particular site. It cannot be used within either of the Location, Directory or Files container directives, **nor can it be used within a “.htaccess” file.**

(emphasis mine)